# One Independent Trial, What is the Chance of One Result Occurring First?

Tags: probability

Each trial can result in one of three possible results.

Result A happens 50% of the time.
Result B happens 30% of the time.
Result C happens 20% of the time.

Each trial is independent.

I want to know what is the probability that Result C three times before Result A happens once.

Edited to clarify that it is "at least" three times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Exactly** three times before the first occurrence of A or **at least** three times? We solve under the interpretation *exactly*, and then make a remark about *at least*.

*Edit:* OP has indicated that he wants "at least." But I might as well leave the answer below unchanged, a two for one deal.

First of all, occurrences of B do not matter, so we can assume the probability of A is $5/7$, and the probability of $C$ is $2/7$.

The probability $C$ happens before A is $2/7$. Now the process starts again, so by independence the probability that this happens three times is $(2/7)^3$. The probability that then A happens first is $5/7$, so the required probability is $(2/7)^3(5/7)$.

*Remark*: The problem is a little simpler under the interpretation *at least* three times. The reasoning above showed that the probability is then $(2/7)^3$.

Comment: Good point, I will clarify that I mean AT LEAST 3 times. 
Logically I agree with your answer but I’m running into an issue I have trouble reconciling. 
If we reframe the question slightly:
P(A) = 24%
P(C) = 3%
What is the probability of getting A six times before C?
I believe your equation would say its slightly less than 50% (24/27)^3. 
But on average the number of trials required to get six A results should be 6/.24 = 25. 
On average it should take 33 trials (1/0.03) to get one C. 
Shouldn’t the likelihood of getting 6 A results before C be much higher than 50%?

Comment: @ShengFeng: The probability of at least $6$ A results before C is $(24/27)^6$, which is indeed about $50$ percent. Since we are not even recording B results, the expected waiting time until $C$ occurs is $27/3$, much smaller than your $33$.

Comment: Perhaps my lack of familiarity with probabilities is showing, but taking out the B results shouldn't affect the relative probability of A and C right? If the expected sample size to get SIX A results is smaller than getting ONE C result, you should expect to get SIX A results before a C results much more often than 50% of the time right?

Comment: @ShengFeng:  Intuition is useful, but in matters of probability it can be deceptive. The intuition is likely to be more accurate for exactly $6$ A. before the first C. However, let's stick to at least. The expected waiting time before we get $6$ A is $6(27/24)$, that is, $6.75$. That is not terribly far away from $27/3$ (previous comment).